# Nxlog unable to send eventlog after certain time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, event-log, nxlog

I'm using `ElasticSearch` / `Logstash` / `Kibana` to centralize my logs.

On the servers I'm running `NXlog` to send eventlogs. It's been running fine for a couple of days, but while troubleshooting something it stopped receiving any logs.

From my NXlog log:

> ERROR couldn't connect to tcp socket on *.*.*.*:port_no; No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

and `Elastic` search is throwing exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./.ddos2.4": error=2, No such file or           
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    ... 36 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
```

Comment: Please check: 1. All process are running in server(where you want to send the log msg) 2. In Server is listening to correct port number. 3. In server any firewall rule is blocking this? 4. Restart all process(client and server) then check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a virus on your system. Please search on /tmp/sx or somthing like this. It's 99% that your elasticsearch server is compromised.
http://www.computerworld.com/article/2490432/cloud-security/attackers-install-ddos-bots-on-amazon-cloud--exploit-elasticsearch-weakness.html
http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/33370/